# Outputting searched data to another form

Tags: php, html, sql, search

I'm currently building a system which gets a unique value and uses that as a login i.e a reference number. The reference number then searches the database and outputs all corresponding data to another page, I am struggling with this, my code is:

Index.PHP

```
<input name="search_box"  type="text" class="auto-style1" id="search_box" style="width: 240px; height: 30px" maxlength="12">

<input type="submit" name="search" value="Enter" class="auto-style1" style="width: 63px; height: 30px"></td>
<?php $reasons = array("search_box" => "Please Enter Valid Reference Number", "" => "Error"); if ($_GET["loginFailed"]) echo $reasons[$_GET["reason"]]; ?>

</form>
```

Check.php

```
 <?php
include "conn.php";

mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die(header("location:index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=search_box"));
mysql_select_db("DB1") or die(header("location:index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=search_box"));

$reference1 = $_POST['search_box'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table1 WHERE No =$R1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result)
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    else
    $count = 0;

if($count == 1)
 {
  session_register('search_box');
  header("location:result.php");
  }
else 
{
echo (header("location:index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=search_box"));
 }
 ?>
```

Output.php

```
 <?php
include "conn.php";

$sq2 = "SELECT * FROM test_table1";
if (isset($_POST['search']))
 {
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sq2 .= "WHERE No =  '{$search_term}'";
}

$query= mysql_query($sq2, $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
&nbsp;<font size="4" face="Calibri"><b> Ref Number:   </b> </font><?php echo $row['No']; ?></td>
<p>
&nbsp;<font size="4" face="Calibri"><b> Location:   </b></font><?php echo $row['Country']; ?></td>
<p>

<?php
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help you guys could give would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Qwerty.

Comment: you should escape or re-type your $reference1 to (int) in Login_check.php what is not very safe. Also saying where is the problem would speed up the answer - eg. what it does that it shouldn't and what it doesn't do what it should :)

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the desired behavior and what is the current behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i am assuming that you have one table `donations` where you have some `donId` (reference No.) of the donation, `donName` of the person donating, `donCountry` the country the donator is from and `donAmount` how much money they donated.
Your file would look something like this (i will not bother with all the proper headers for html, so the result will not be a w3c valid html but it should work in your browser without problems.

I think i MUST say that you should not use the `mysql_query` and all other `mysql_...` functions use instead `mysqli_*`. The following code though is still using the old these days already deprecated mysql_ functions, so it's in your interest to upgrade it accordingly to mysqli (that's a home work ;) lol )

File `donInfo.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action='donInfo.php' method='post'>
    <label for='donId'>Reference No.:</label>
    <input type='text' size='6' name='donId' id='donId' value='' />
    <input type='submit' name='do' value='  Show me!  ' style='margin-left:2em;'/>
</form>

<?php
    /* table definition: 
    CREATE TABLE donations (
        donId int unsigned not null,
        donCountry varchar(80) not null,
        donName varchar(80) not null,
        donAmount numeric(11,2) not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (donId)
    )
    */
    if (!isset($_POST['do']) || !isset($_POST['donId']) || !$_POST['donId']) 
        exit;

    require_once 'connection.php';

    $don=mysql_fetch_assoc(
        mysql_query('SELECT * '.
            'FROM donations '.
            'WHERE donId="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['donId'],$con).'"',$con));
    if ($don===false || !$don['donId'])
        print '<h3>Donation id #'.$_POST['donId'].' does not exist!</h3>';
    else {
        print '<h3>Information about donation id #'.$_POST['donId'].'</h3>'.
            'State: '.$don['donCountry'].'<br/>'.
            'Donator: '.$don['donName'].'<br/>'.
            'Amount: $ '.number_format($don['donAmount'],2).'<br/>'.
            '<hr/>';

        $sumP=mysql_fetch_assoc(
            mysql_query('SELECT SUM(donAmount) total, COUNT(*) donx '.
                'FROM donations '.
                'WHERE donName="'.mysql_real_escape_string($don['donName'],$con).'" '.
                'GROUP BY donName',$con));
        print '<h4>Donations from '.$don['donName'].':</h4>'.
            'Total Amount: $ '.number_format($sumP['total'],2).'<br/>'.
            'Donated <b>'.number_format($sumP['donx'],0).'</b> times to date.<br/>'.
            '<hr/>';

        $sumC=mysql_fetch_assoc(
            mysql_query('SELECT SUM(donAmount) total, COUNT(DISTINCT donName) donators, COUNT(*) donx '.
                'FROM donations '.
                'WHERE donCountry="'.mysql_real_escape_string($don['donCountry'],$con).'" '.
                'GROUP BY donCountry',$con));
        print '<h4>Donations from '.$don['donCountry'].':</h4>'.
            'Total Amount: $ '.number_format($sumC['total'],2).'<br/>'.
            'Total of <b>'.number_format($sumC['donx']).'</b> donations from <b>'.number_format($sumC['donators'],0).'</b> donators.<br/>'.
            '<hr/>';

        $sumW=mysql_fetch_assoc(
            mysql_query('SELECT SUM(donAmount) total, COUNT(DISTINCT donName) donators, COUNT(DISTINCT donCountry) countries, COUNT(*) donx '.
                'FROM donations '.
                'GROUP BY 1=1',$con));
        print '<h4>Donations Total:</h4>'.
            'Total Amount: $ '.number_format($sumW['total'],2).'<br/>'.
            'Total of <b>'.number_format($sumW['donx']).'</b> donations from <b>'.number_format($sumW['countries'],0).'</b> countries and <b>'.number_format($sumW['donators'],0).'</b> donators.<br/>'.
            '<hr/>';        
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested the code, so it should work well. i'm using your `connection.php` script where (i guess) you are initializing your database.

short description of what it does:
Asks for an ID, then when submited it checks whether it exist or not and if yes, it will print information about THAT donation id, information about user of that id, about country of that id and total donation statistic. If the donation Id does not exist, it will just say: does not exist while waiting for another ID to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

You problem (the one you are probably wondering about right now (as there seems to be a few more potencial ones and exploits)) is in `Output.php`.

At the time you call that file from `Login_check.php` (because you are redirecting te browser) you'r `$_POST` array does no longer contain any data.

To make it easier on yourself, why not `include "Output.php";` instead of redirecting the browser by `headers()`? That way you would not need to reinitialize the session or database in the `Output.php` again.

If you require this redirect however, store your `$_POST['search']` to `$_SESSION['search']` after your session is initialized and then reffer to `$_SESSION['search']` in `Output.php` instead of (as you have it now) to `$_POST['search']`

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: @qwerty255 in `Login_check.php` update this part of your code to: `if($count == 1) { session_register('search_box'); iclude 'Output.php'; } else ...` and in `Output.php` replace `include "connection.php";` with `include_once "connection.php";` your code should work a little more than it did so far. I doubt i can help you any more without you explaining well what are you trying to do, because it is not very clear to me. For example why is your sutrcture the way it is (why so many files, why redirects, do you even need playing with sessions).

Comment: @qwerty255 Hi, i think you are complicating it too much. It sounds to me like you only need one php file where it will print some `Enter ID to check: [____] [Submit]` input on top and under than, when you "submit" an id (form pointing to the same php script) it will display the desired information. Mind you, this approach isn't safe and anyone who really wants and can access that site will eventually hit existing ref.No. and see some personal details, so **careful** with it. If you want me to post here something that you could tweak yourself let me know and i may post in another answer.

Comment: @qwerty255 I believe that it is simple enough. could you write me here somewhere your table structures, so that i can give you your exact code?

Comment: @qwerty255 Hi. to output more you need to keep fetching new rows (as long as there are any, or) as long as you want them. It's usually done like this: `$q=mysql_query("select ..."); while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { var_dump($r); }` You will of course use your an actual sql query instead of the `"select ..."` and will do more useful action than just `var_dump($r);` inside the `while` cycle